# Get categories for a specific post - Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm trying to retrieve all the categories which are related to a specific post, using the `wp_get_post_categories()` function. The problem is that it is a custom post type, so I tried sending it in the $args array :

```
wp_get_post_categories($id,array('post_type'=>'product'));
```

but that returned an empty array as well.
What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it a `category`, and not a custom [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)?

If it is a category try:

```
var_dump( wp_get_post_categories( $id ) );
```

or its equivalent since `category` is a taxonomy:

```
var_dump( wp_get_object_terms( $id, 'category' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post-type `product` has probably it's own "category" taxonomy. Try:

```
wp_get_object_terms( $id, '<your-custom-product-category-taxonomy>', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```