# Retrieve a specific category of posts when using a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to retrieve a specific category within a custom post type of portfolio.  I don't know what I have to put in the query to only get certain posts?  Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php // Create and run custom loop
    $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
    $custom_posts->query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=-1');
    while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
  ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>

<?php 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I've included [image: two screenshots] from the database, I'm trying to retrieve the posts from 'portfolio_categories' with term_id 4.

I did search prior to posting and found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82738/get-categories-for-a-specific-post-custom-post-type), but I still don't understand.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)?

Comment: @Milo yes I have.

Comment: and did you try anything? I linked to the section that explains what you need to add.

Comment: I tried this and it worked  query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=-1&slug=past-projects&portfolio_categories=past-projects');

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so that question doesn't haunt site as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 0):

the answer my question is:

```
query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=-1&slug=past-projects&portfolio_catego‌​ries=past-projects');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes a difference but I probably would have written it this way myself:

```
$args =  array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_catego‌​ries',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'past-projects'
            )
        )
);

$custom_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

<?php 
while ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>

<?php 

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```